# Control stops working after animating it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, storyboard

**I have a slider named `tbMaster` :**

```
<Slider  Name="tbMaster"  Maximum="10000"  Value="{Binding SbVolumeValue}"/>
```

**code behind for binded property:**

```
    double _SbVolumeValue;
    public double SbVolumeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _SbVolumeValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _SbVolumeValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SbVolumeValue");
        }
    }
```

**I have the storyboard `sbVolume`**

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="sbVolume">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="tbMaster">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="40">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

---

if I run the application the slider works great. It stops working when I begin the storyboard as:

```
 var sbVolume = this.FindResource("sbVolume") as Storyboard;
 sbVolume.Begin();
```

why does it stops working after I animate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a [`FillBehavior.Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior) to your Animation. The default is `FillBehavior.HoldEnd`.

From Above Link:

> Because an animation in its fill period continues to override its target property's value, attempting to set the target property's value through other means might appear to have no effect. For an example showing how to set a property value after it has been animated, see [How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493)

Comment: Thanks that works great! the slider comes back to it's starting position after animating. I guess that will not be hard to fix. I will work on that... thanks a lot for the help